# Can a website pass focus to the browsers url field?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

Can I create a piece of code for my website which focuses the browser url bar (field) so I can directly start typing in a new url?

There could be for example a predefined hotkey which would execute this code.

**Background:** My (mouse-less) webapp steals the focus when loaded, so keyboard shortcuts can work. Users requested a possibility to easily access the browser url bar by hitting the space key.

*Even if it is not possible, I can answer now I tried anything possible. :)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope you can't do it with your own code.

In most browsers though, the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

- [Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306832): <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>
- [Mozilla Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts): <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>
- [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95743): <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>
- [Opera](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.51/en/keyboard.html): <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>
- [Safari](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=42951) (Mac): <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>